# Defining second parameter as a conditional type based on the value of the first paramenter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function with two parameters. I want to set the type of the second parameter as a conditional type based on the value of the first parameter. How is this possible

This is the sample code:

```js
type Event<T> = T extends 'string'? string : number;

function test(module:'string'|'number', event:Event<typeof module>)
{
  //...
}

// The second argument is of type string | number
// But it should be string
test('string',2)
```

The second parameter is always of type `string|number`.

Comment: Can you use generics again - `test<T extends 'string'|'number'>(module: T, event: Event<T>)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your function generic to solve this issue.

```js
function test<T extends string | number>(module: T, event: Event<T>) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Note the OP is using a string literal type, not a union type.

Comment: This solves the problem. But what when the function is generic itself? like this: `function<T,U>(module: U, event: Event<U>)`. Then how can I call the function passing just one type? `test<User>('string', 2)` generates error

Comment: @rostamiani what do you mean *"the function is generic itself"*? You don't seem to be using `T` in your definition, so what's the point of it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe As this seems to be another question, I asked it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62673801/how-can-i-call-a-generic-function-with-just-one-generic-parameter-when-the-secon