# How can I call a generic function with just one generic parameter when the second one is needed on the fly?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have a generic function with two parameters. The second one is based on the value of first parameter.

The code works with just one *type variable* but when I add another one, cannot call the function.

**This works perfectly:**

```js
type Event<T> = T extends 'string' ? string : number;
type input = 'string' | 'number';

function test<U extends input>(module: U, event: Event<U>) {
  //...
}

//No errors
test('number', 2);

// Generates error as expected
test('string', 2);
```

**But when another generic variable is needed, we have error:**

```js
type Event<T> = T extends 'string' ? string : number;
type input = 'string' | 'number';

function test<T, U extends input>(module: U, event: Event<U>) {

  // The subject factory returns a new Rxjs Subject
  return subjectFactory<T>(module + '-' + event);
}

// Works without any generic parameter
const s1 = test('number', 2);

// Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1
const s2 = test<MyType>('number', 2);
```

I need to call the function without the second generic parameter. How?

Comment: I believe partial type inference is WIP: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242. In this case though it seems odd to have an internal generic type that's unrelated to the parameter types - what would cause it to change?

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is my previous question that's solved but I need an additional generic parameter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62672550

Comment: Yes, I know; I've commented on both of them. My question is *why* do you think you need this additional parameter? How does the type need change inside the function in a way that doesn't depend on the parameter or return types?

Comment: My real function adds a new Rxjs `Subject<T>` to a local array. Then I have to pass the `T` type to define the Subject inside the function

Comment: Please [edit] the question to provide the context - where does that `T` come from, what other types involved does it relate to?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Thanks. You're right, There is a problem. In real world the solution isn't working. I added a more realistic example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62672550/defining-second-parameter-as-a-conditional-type-based-on-the-value-of-the-first

Comment: Please don't ping-pong between two questions, or edit once you've received an answer. Here it seems like the subject is always going to be of `string`, so it's not really clear why a generic type is needed.